# Parametisation of the intersection between a cylinder and a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Give a parametrisation of the intersection of the plane -18x +3y -10z -37 = 0
with the cylinder $\ (x − 1)^2 \ $ + $\ (y − 4)^2 \ $ = 25

I believe this would be solved by taking the parametic equations of the projection of the cylinder on the xy plane, then substitute the x and y in the equation of the plane with those of the parametic equations of the cylinder and solve for z. then use the parametic equations of the cylinder and the solved value for z to form a vector equation.

However i do not know how to get the parametic equations for the projection of the cylinder. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametrisation you are looking for is $x = 5\cos(t) + 1$ and $y = 5\sin (t) + 4$, the rest is what you said!

The key to find the parametrisation is noticing the projection of the cyilinder is a circle of radius $5$, and of course the parametrisation of a circle of radius $R$
centered at $(0,0)$
is $(R \cos (t) , R \sin (t))$, now in your problem the cylinder its center at $(1,4)$, so just add this point.

Comment: Thanks! But how did you arrive at this parametrisation?

Comment: See the edit :-) @V.Stuart